# How can I create an indexed binary tree from a sorted list in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to make a tree out of a sorted list so that I can search it later.

### The problem is

I have to return the index of the number if it is found else I return -1, so I created this function.

```hs
data Tree e i = Leaf e i | Node (Tree e i) e i (Tree e i)
    

occurs :: Int -> Tree Int Int -> Int 
occurs x (Leaf y i)     | x == y    = i 
                        | otherwise = -1
occurs x (Node l y i r) | x == y    = i 
                        | x < y     = occurs x l 
                        | otherwise = occurs x r
```

My input is comming in the format (as a string)

```
3       # The length of as
1 5 7   # as
2       # The length of bs
5 6     # bs
```

where I receive 2 lists `as` and `bs`
`as` is gonna be the Tree and `bs` is the numbers I want to check if they exist in the tree (and where)

And the expected output is:

```
1
-1
```

where 5 is found on index 1 and 6 is not found so I return -1

So I am parsing the input:

```hs
parse :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
parse (n: xs) = (take n xs, tail $ drop n xs) 

solve :: [Int] -> [Int]
solve xs = func as bs
    where (as, bs) = parse xs

main ::IO ()
main = interact $ unlines . map show . solve . map read . words
```

And then I need to call a function `func` which will create my tree from the list `as` and then use the `occurs` function to search the tree for each element in `bs`

### So my question is

- How can I make the tree so that it contains the indexes, from the lists?
- And is my type created in the right way for this problem?

My Haskell level = reached the Types and classes chapter, in the Cambridge Haskell book by GH, and following the HaskellRank series on youtube.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but returning an `Int` and artificially signalling a non-existent index with -1, is not the "Haskell way" even though it's common in other languages. It requires boilerplate to ensure the index is non-negative, which is easy to forget if you expect to find the element. It's better to return a `Maybe Int`, with `Nothing` returned if the element isn't found - this is more descriptive and also means that you can't treat the result as an `Int` without also handling the case where it doesn't exist.

Comment: It looks like your tree must be a BST to make your `occurs` function work. You probably will need some `insert` function that, given a BST and a key-element pair, inserts it in the BST (by returning a new BST). This might produce a balanced BST (e.g. AVL, red-black, ...) or not, but the important part is that it has to produce a BST. Then you can exploit this `insert` function to build your tree processing the elements one-by-one. (Other approaches are also possible, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a Binary Search Tree using a divide and conquer approach and keep a similar version of yours 'occurs' method:

1. Take the element at center of the ordered list as root. If there are ties (the list has even length) choose any you like. It doesn't matter.
2. Recursively solve the problem with all elements to the left of the selected index and add the returned tree as left child of current root. If there are no elements to the left then add a null reference on the left child.
3. Recursively solve the problem with all elements to the right of the selected index and add the returned tree as right child of current root. If there are no elements to the right then add a null reference on the right child.

This divide and conquer approach guarantees a O(log n) height of the tree where n is length of the ordered list. The construction of the tree is O(n) and is a correct binary search tree because as the list is ordered we know that all elements on the left side are lower or equal than the current one and all elements on the right side are greater or equal than the current one.

The type creation is flaw as your construction of a tree rely on leaf nodes and nodes that have not null left and right child which is not true in almost any input. You can try to construct a tree with 2 nodes to see what i mean. Other not so Haskell design is the use of -1 as no existence of solution since Haskell has an integrated type of Maybe created for these cases but if you need to do that it's at the end your choice.